# How to launch netflix app with specific movie in windows 10 externally?

Tags: windows-8, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal, windows-10-desktop

I am able to launch netflix app in windows 10 from my own app using launcher (Netflix://), but its failed to launch a specific movie using launcher like netflix://www.netflix.com/watch/70021664).

Comment: This depend on if the netflix [handle the URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation). If it handled you may need to know the detail protocol, not the one you think about, you may need to ask the netflix team. On my side , I even cannot see one movie since I don't have an paid account, I don't think this can be directly launched.

Comment: @Thameem how do you call it? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Netflix App is written in WinJS its easy to read through the Code.

There are 5 Commands I found:

- browseVideoId
- playVideoId
- searchTerm
- viewDownloads
- findSomethingToDownload

So to execute them use following Code:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"netflix:/app?playVideoId=12345678"));
```

I recognized, that if Netflix is not opened it only starts the App. Calling the same Code again, then executes the command. Still figuring out a way to solve this.

To get the Id of the Series / Video you want to browse / play open it in your browser. In the sample Link I provided you are looking for the (in my case 8-Digit Id) I replaced by **videoId**:

https://www.netflix.com/watch/**videoId**?trackId=00000000